# How to accept `Box<dyn Error + Send>` in places that accept `Box<dyn Error>`?

Tags: rust

Can I accept a `Box<dyn Error + Send>` in places that accept `Box<dyn Error>`? If yes, how? If no, why, and is there a more elegant way to do it than in the following example?

```rust
#![allow(unused)]

use std::error::Error as StdError;
use std::result::Result as StdResult;

type    Result = StdResult<(), Box< dyn StdError >>;
type SndResult = StdResult<(), Box< dyn StdError + Send >>;

fn fn_returning_result()    ->    Result { Ok(()) }
fn fn_returning_sndresult() -> SndResult { Ok(()) }

/// Accept a callback that returns a non-Send `Result`.
fn register_callback<CB: FnOnce() -> Result>(cb: CB) { /* ... */ }

fn main() -> Result {
    // Is there a way to get rid of ... vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv ... this part?
    let cb = || fn_returning_sndresult().map_err(|e| -> Box<dyn StdError> { e });
    register_callback(cb);

    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eab225b1358ebdc40867dcb15d0a4642)

Edit: What I would like to do here is just `let cb = || fn_returning_sndresult();`, but that won't compile.

Also, I'd like to call either `fn_returning_result()?` or `fn_returning_sndresult()?` inside the callback with a single return type and without doing a `map_err`.

Comment: On my trip through Google results, I came across the following issue: [Send/Sync additional trait requirements cannot be automatically relaxed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/45716). It basically says that `Box<dyn Error + ...> => Box<dyn Error>` coercion was removed, but I'm still not sure what to do about it as a user.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on an answer I got [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/btj5ik/hey_rustaceans_got_an_easy_question_ask_here/ep0v6c4?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) by Llaurence_:

I can change `register_callback` to accept both `Box<dyn Error>` and `Box<dyn Error + Send>` errors by making the error type generic:

```rust
fn register_callback<CB, E>(cb: CB)
where
    CB: FnOnce() -> StdResult<(), Box<E>>,
    E: StdError + ?Sized,
{ /* ... */ }
```

Now I can pass a callback that returns either kind of error / result:

```rust
register_callback(fn_returning_result);
register_callback(fn_returning_sndresult);
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: Can I accept a `Box<dyn Error + Send>` in places that accept `Box<dyn Error>`?

A: Yes, with some newtype wrapping. The solution I finally ended up with was this: ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4f46077d20dcd2184ca2ac23d4b47c0c))

```rust
use std::error::Error as StdError;
use std::result::Result as StdResult;
use std::fmt;

type    Result = StdResult<(), Box< dyn StdError >>;
type SndResult = StdResult<(), Box< dyn StdError + Send >>;

fn fn_returning_result()    ->    Result { dbg!(Err("oops".into())) }
fn fn_returning_sndresult() -> SndResult { dbg!(Ok(())) }

/// Result type using `Er` defined below.
type Rt<T = ()> = StdResult<T, Er>;


// Error wrapper

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Er(Box<dyn StdError>);

impl fmt::Display for Er {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt::Debug::fmt(self, f)
    }
}

impl StdError for Er {}


// Allow `?` operator

impl From<Box<dyn StdError>> for Er {
    fn from(err: Box<dyn StdError>) -> Self {
        Er(err)
    }
}

impl From<Box<dyn StdError + Send>> for Er {
    fn from(err: Box<dyn StdError + Send>) -> Self {
        Er(err)
    }
}


// List of callbacks

struct Callbacks<'a>(Vec<Box<dyn FnOnce() -> Rt + 'a>>);

impl<'a> Callbacks<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Callbacks(Vec::new())
    }

    fn add(&mut self, cb: impl FnOnce() -> Rt + 'a) {
        self.0.push(Box::new(cb));
    }

    fn pop_and_call(&mut self) -> Rt {
        self.0.pop().unwrap()()
    }
}


// Example

fn main() -> Result {
    let mut callbacks = Callbacks::new();

    callbacks.add(|| { Ok(fn_returning_result()?) });
    callbacks.add(|| { Ok(fn_returning_sndresult()?) });

    callbacks.pop_and_call()?;
    callbacks.pop_and_call()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Note that the callbacks can use `?` on either `Result` or `SndResult` values (thanks to the `From` trait impls), and that their return values are valid `Result`s as well, allowing `main` to also use `?` on their calls (thanks to the `StdError` trait impl).